# How to compress html output in php?

Tags: php, html, compression

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to minify php page html output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225351/how-to-minify-php-page-html-output)

I mean strip out all the line breaks and spaces in html and puts it on one line.

I tried this function

```
public static function htmlCompress($html)
{
    preg_match_all('!(<(?:code|pre|script).*>[^<]+</(?:code|pre|script)>)!',$html,$pre);
    $html = preg_replace('!<(?:code|pre).*>[^<]+</(?:code|pre)>!', '#pre#', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('#<!–[^\[].+–>#', '', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/[\r\n\t]+/', ' ', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/>[\s]+</', '><', $html);
    $html = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', $html);
    if (!empty($pre[0])) {
        foreach ($pre[0] as $tag) {
            $html = preg_replace('!#pre#!', $tag, $html,1);
        }
    }
    return $html;
}
```

but sometimes appears symbols like "�" because of this string

```
$html = preg_replace('/[\s]+/', ' ', $html);
```

Why appears this symbol and how to compress html?

Comment: Use an existing library [html minifier](http://code.google.com/p/htmlcompressor/)

Comment: That usually means there is a mismatch in your character sets, for instance, one is ASCII and the other UTF-8.

Comment: You achieve more by just gzipping the content. HTML minifaction is only useful for sites with massive userbases.

Comment: @Ibu that's a Java library. Can be used in conjunction with PHP of course (the question's about PHP), just saying...a PHP solution probably makes more sense here.

Comment: This function have a bug; line-breaks get damaged when pre include html-tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That symbol means it's a foreign character and your particular font doesn't know what character it needs to use. You should look into [multibyte-safe string functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) and UTF-8 [encoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-encode.php) and [decoding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.utf8-decode.php)

Answer (score 5):

\s should not appear in square brackets, i.e. this is correct:

```
$html = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $html);
```

Comment: Wonderful and simple, thanks. It is the only one that does not break the code. One suggestion to add: $html = str_replace( '> <', '><', $html );

Answer (score 1):

Look into output buffering: http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php
and http://php.net/manual/en/function.gzcompress.php (if your apache server is configured to handle compression.)
Any more then that will likely cause more overhead then you would gain.

So, use the ob_buffer to get your output as a string. Compress the string, and send it out.