# Minify PHP/html code

Tags: php, yii

I need to minify html code to improve my website performance using PHP

I'm using Yii PHP Framework / Apache.

Comment: Sounds awesome. Do it.

Comment: Minification is to reduce how long it takes the browser to download a file.  Performance problems in PHP code are more likely to be caused by the code taking too long to *run* on the server, which has nothing to do with how fast the browser can download the output.  Are you sure that minification will solve the right problem?

Comment: @Wyzard what if I have good server ?

Comment: Are you already gzipping all your content and assets? I feel like there are much better ways to improve performance than minifying html source.

Comment: @AnasA Good server doesn't mean good code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to minify php page html output?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225351/how-to-minify-php-page-html-output)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [PageSpeed Module](https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module) from google it's really great

Answer (score 1):

Extensions for Yii:

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/escriptboost

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/minscript

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/clientscriptpacker

http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/dynamicres/