# How to call ob_gzhandler after ob_start has already been called?

Tags: php, output, gzip, minify

I'm using code from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6225706/1322720) to minify HTML and then `ob_gzhandler` to gzip the page (because `mode_deflate` is disabled on my shared server and therefore I cannot gzip in .htaccess):

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {

    $buffer = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+\s*/', '', $buffer);

    return $buffer;
}

ob_start("sanitize_output");
if(!ob_start("ob_gzhandler")) ob_start();
```

Both `ob_start("sanitize_output")` and `ob_start("ob_gzhandler")` work well on their own, but combining them causes a content encoding error:

[image]

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put `ob_start("ob_gzhandler")` before `ob_start("sanitize_output")`

```
function sanitize_output($buffer) {
    $buffer = preg_replace('/[\r\n]+\s*/', '', $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
if(substr_count($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_ENCODING'], 'gzip')){
    ob_end_clean();
    ob_start('ob_gzhandler');
    ob_start("sanitize_output");
}
else {
    ob_start();
}
```

Don't forget to use `ob_end_flush();` at the end.