# PHP minify function seems to destroy inline JS?

Tags: javascript, php, minify

I have the following minify function:

```
public static function minify($buffer)
{
    $search = array(
        '/\>[^\S ]+/s',
        '/[^\S ]+\</s',
        '/(\s)+/s'
    );
    $replace = array(
        '>',
        '<',
        '\\1'
    );
    $buffer = preg_replace($search, $replace, $buffer);
    return $buffer;
}
```

This function is used with `ob_start()` in order to minify my html output. The function is taken from here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6225706/4601581

This function seems to destroy some of my JS. Example: A button i click to execute some JS:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-<?= Config::$ELEMENT_COLOR ?> btn-block" onclick="addLastInput(<?= $mask->getId() ?>)">Do it</button>
```

The `$id` i give to addLastInput is simply a number, taken from `$mask->getId()`.

Also i have this little JS code to populate some data array:

```
<script>lastSubmissionData[<?=$mask->getId()?>] = '<?=json_encode($lastSubmissionData)?>';</script>
```

And finally my JS function i actually want to execute with my given param (the id) and on the data array:

```
function addLastInput(maskId) {
        var data = lastSubmissionData[maskId];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            // TODO
        }
    }
```

Whenever i only load the page, it simply tells me `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input` in the Chrome console. Whenever i do so with not using the minify function and outcommenting the `ob_start()` completely, it just works and i can use it.

Conclusion: The minify function seems to brake my inline JS as the comments on the linked SO answer suggest. Question: How can i fix that? I even googled for other minify solutions like this one: https://gist.github.com/tovic/d7b310dea3b33e4732c0

All of them seem to not work by just breaking my site. What's the best solution here to simply let me use my JS code and still minify my html output?

Comment: Put your javascript in an external file, problem solved. On the other hand, entire libraries are written to try and handle minifying properly, and they still fail at times, just doing it with a couple of regular expressions is bound to have issues.

Comment: Put js code in a js file and don't use inline JavaScript at all.

Comment: @Michael: Problem is, that i can only put the function itself in the extern .js file. Not really the <script> // Fill my data array here</script>. Because at page load, my PHP code is actually generating a lot of data that is written to JS variables for later use. I can't put that into extern .js files.

Comment: Then it will be better to use ajax to load the data once the page has been loaded. This will also make your page load faster

Comment: @Michael: Ok, and let's say i can't do that for whatever reason. How can i still use that inline JS for populating my JS array with data in the pageload by PHP while not breaking it with the minify?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use this `minify()` function. It's broken.**

This function ends up removing some semantically meaningful newlines in inline Javascript code, such as ones appearing at the end of a single-line comment. (For example, it converts your example Javascript function to a single line ending in `{ // TODO } }`.)

This function will break some HTML constructs as well. In particular, it will destroy the content of `<pre>` tags, as it does not recognize that whitespace is significant in that context.

(Both of these caveats are mentioned in highly upvoted comments on the post you got this code from, by the way!)