# Replace in whole wordpress page html

Tags: php, wordpress

In order to optimize my website I want to replace several things in a whole HTML. I was able to replace things in the content with the following function:

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('look-for-this-string', 'replace-with-this-string', $text);
    return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

But, for example to minify the generated html I want to delete the line breaks. Is there a way of doing so in functions.php? How can I archive this?

Comment: If your method works, so why not to add `$text = str_replace(array("\r", "\n"), '', $text);` before `return $text`? Our create another filter for minifying and call it next.

Comment: @GinoPane I want it to work in whole html, not just the content.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6225351/how-to-minify-php-page-html-output <--you can use a modified version of this

Answer (score 0):

You can either use or check how it's done in existing plugins, can't you?
For example:

[WP Super Minify](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-super-minify/)

This will give you not only a solution, but also you will have a nice opportunity to check how people are writing plugins. And who knows, maybe you could even contribute to this plugin?