# How Google, Facebook and other websites minify their html?

Tags: html

In the `View Page Source`, I see this kind of minified html output in most websites like `Google` and `Facebook`, here is the simplified example.

```
<html><head>/.../</head><body><div><div>/.../</div></div><div>/.../</div></body></head>
```

- What this kind of html output method does?
- May this kind of method help a small websites?
- What do I need to do to make my `html` output like this?

Comment: What do you mean here? All html pages will be like this right..

Comment: I have no idea what you’re asking. What “kind” of HTML output do you mean? I don’t see anything special about it. What “method” are you refering to?

Comment: minified html.. try http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Comment: I tried to use `View Page Source` to Google, Facebook and Stackoverflow, there is a big difference, Google and Facebook, their html codes are in full horizontal line, Stackoverflow on the other hand is the opposite. If you have the time to spare, please use `View Page Source` any pages of Google, Facebook and Stackoverflow and you will see the difference in the html codes display.

Comment: They all minified their html

Comment: They all are minifying the html and I have posted the answer with more details

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google, Facebook and many other sites are minifying their HTML by removing unnecessary white spaces and new lines from the HTML to send them faster to improve the performance. That’s why you can see them in one line like how we are minifying the JS and CSS files.

There are many npm modules to take care of this and automate the process and below are a few of them:

- [html-minifier](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minifier)
- [html-minify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/html-minify)
- [gulp-minify-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-minify-html)
- [express-minify-html](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-minify-html)

Comment: So Google and Facebook for example have their own html minifier program or system?

Comment: They won't disclose what they are using, but there are many modules almost in all the server languages.

Comment: Thanks, this really helps me a lot. In addition, can I install html-minifier in a shared hosting environment?

Comment: Yes you can but if you have any CI tool and build environment, automate the process with `grunt` or `gulp` tasks for static html files. But if you have any dynamic pages then you can install the module in the hosting environment.

Comment: can I make my own html minifier? I can't install a module in a shared hosting environment.

Comment: Which server side programming language you are using?

Comment: I am using PHP.

Comment: Can you google for any php html minifier? It should be there a one already.

Comment: Yes, thanks, I am currently searching for a simple one, there is too many though it's quite hard to understand I will study about this.

Comment: I found this answer which makes the html output in one straight line and no line breaks. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1418780/removing-new-lines-except-in-pre/10423788#10423788

Comment: Yes you can give a try of this :-)

Comment: Thanks, it works great. Thank you for your response!