# Remove unwanted line feeds from an HTML file

Tags: php, html, regex

I have a lot of HTML files which have unwanted line-feeds. These break things like inline javascript and formatting within the pages. I want to come up with a way to strip out all line feeds from the pages that do not appear directly after an html tag e.g `</div>`. Does anyone know of a regex and/or program that may be able to acheive this?

Comment: You might benefit from a minifier.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification/1102101.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus.sourceforge.net/)'s search/replace function, with a regular expression to catch most of this.

Something like:

```
([^>])\n(.+)
```

Replaced with:

```
\1 \2
```

Comment: Depending on the format of the html file, you may need to use ([^>])\r\n(.+) or ([^>])\r(.+) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a negative lookbehind to match the line feeds

```
<?php

$buffer = file_get_contents('test.html');

// replace all line feeds not preceded by </div>
$buffer = preg_replace('|(?<!</div>)[\r\n]|', "", $buffer);

file_put_contents('test.new.html', $buffer);
?>
```

see: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Or just use the RE: (?<!</div>)[\r\n]  in your favorite editor.

Comment: you may actually want something more like
    (?<!</[^>]+>)(\r?\n){2,}
i.e. any closing tag with more than 1 CRLF (where CR is optional)