# downloadable html5 & css3 compressors?

Tags: html, css, compression

is there any downloadable, html5 & css3 compressors that i could put on my site for people to use since I don't quite have the knowledge, or time, or money to do it myself?

Comment: Are you talking about minification? http://www.minifycss.com/

Comment: Try searching for HTML and CSS instead of just HTML5 and CSS3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this topics :

[HTML online minimizer/compressor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654832/html-online-minimizer-compressor)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843871/javascript-and-css-minimizer

Answer (score 1):

For CSS3 you can try [Devilo](http://devilo.us) as most other compressors I tried (including the current YUI compressor) tends to break the CSS3 syntax. It is important that the compression engine recognizes the new properties, else the result you'll get after compression will be very difficult to debug.