# Can we do html code optimimization to minimize the size of the page in mvc3?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, optimization

```
Can we do html code optimimization to minimize the size of the page in mvc3 ?
```

my webside home page is of 4 mb size, and when i perform load testing on that page for 4000-5000 users then page load time will decreases to low,
can i minimize my home page html code.

Answer (score 1):

Related to ---  **[HTML online minimizer/compressor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1654832/html-online-minimizer-compressor)**

Approaches for html minifications are :
Minify the javascript/CSS/HTML - This can be done by removing blank spaces.
Compressing the html package - Can be done by GZIP - because All browsers supprots unzip

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET MVC 3+ comes with a lot of features for Web Optimization:

- [ASP.NET Bundling and Minification](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification)

> Bundling and minification are two techniques you can use in ASP.NET
>   4.5 to improve request load time.  Bundling and minification improves load time by reducing the number of requests to the server and
>   reducing the size of requested assets (such as CSS and JavaScript.)

- [How do I enable gzip compression when using MVC3 on IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6992524/how-do-i-enable-gzip-compression-when-using-mvc3-on-iis7)

> There's a lot of features that you can use to compress your request reponse. These are well covered on the post above.

- [Improving Performance with Output Caching](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)

> Improve the performance of your ASP.NET MVC web applications by taking advantage of output caching.