# Reducing html size

Tags: html, size, reducing

Does anyone have a suggestion on how i can reduce my home page size please
http://www.floorsandchores.net

Comment: You could try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification

Comment: Take 3 steps backwards from your monitor, everything will be smaller.

Comment: Perhaps a question better asked at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: I dislike that right click is blocked on your site. Makes it hard to navigate around and look at the insides. But from what I can see, your HTML looks fine - why do you need to reduce its size?

Comment: `"Sorry, right-click has been disabled"` lol

Comment: I ran an SEO report and it suggested i could minimize the html size. The report gave me a score 78% and i was wondering if i fixed this i could rank higher. I do appear on Google's first page for my keywords but not always in top 3.If it can be improved i will try.

Answer (score 1):

All of the other answers are correct, but there is additional fine tuning you can do. ;-)

1.) You have a million-and-one non-breaking spaces used to do alignment... use CSS instead of this:

```
&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
```

2.) There has to be some better image preloading than the Macromedia preloaders from circa 1999.

3.) Use server-side comments, that don't get pushed to the client

4.) You have a ton of empty `onclick=""` handlers in your code.  If you don't need them, rip them out.

5.) Delete all your empty `font` tags, and strong tags, and divs that aren't being used

6.) Unless you overrode it to be inline, you don't need to add `display:block` to your div's

7.) Your favicon is a BMP file... it should be ICO for IE (and/or PNG for modern browsers)

8.) Drop the right-click blocker - there's no point in it anymore.  All browsers fully expose the entire HTML/JS/CSS for anyone to see in ways you can't block.

9.) Remove/Refactor the JavaScript that is targetting IE4 and Netscape6 - both of these browsers died years ago

10.) You have this meta tag declared twice... `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

11.) You likely don't need this on the links: `target="_self"`

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking about size in kilobytes?

Your page is currently 182K. That's not a whole lot.

To find out the size of your site of find out how to optimize the loading speed, I recommend  [firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/) for firefox and yahoo's [yslow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) (add on to firebug) - it will tell you the page size, how you can optimize the site etc.

According to YSlow, you're currently getting a grade of `C`, which isn't so bad.

---

### Page loading speed

If you're thinking about speeding your site up, there are a few ways.

To speed up the page you can do a few things:

- You currently have 7 javascript files, and 5 css files. The css files can be combined into one and the javascript files can be reduced to (I think) two or three.
- You should actually place the javascript files at the bottom right before the closing `</body>` tag
- You can add "expires headers" - you can do that in an `.htaccess` file (on apache servers at least) - this won't affect new users, but users that come often will feel a difference.

  ---

### GZip compression

You could enable gzip compression on your website. There is a plugin for apache - but it's not certain that your host is compatible. But this will reduce the size considerably.

Answer (score 0):

If you use a tool such as [YSlow](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/) or [Google Page Speed](http://code.google.com/intl/sv/speed/page-speed/) they will tell you what kind of optimizations that would increase the performance of your site. I can tell that your not gzip:ing your html, js-files and so on. Turning on gzip will reduce the size that gets downloaded to the client drastically.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a huge document relatively speaking, but here's what I'd tell my employees if they presented the code for review:

- The Javascript is old-school (looks
  to be auto-generated?) and you could
  minimize what you're sending across
  on each request by utilizing JQuery
  or in cases such as the rollover
  images, pure CSS.
- CSS could be used to remove repetitive element such as the `font-size: 10px;` which is done 17 times in-line on the page.  Just set a CSS property for font with font-size=10px (or better yet, set one for the html and do percentages for child selectors)
- Run the page through a [CSS optimizer](http://www.cleancss.com/)
- Use semantic markup, which will clean up the page and also help with SEO!
- Combine CSS documents to lower the amount of HTTP Requests
- Check in a [W3 Validator](http://validator.w3.org).  Doesn't save space per se, but you are currently reporting 18 errors

Comment: Wow, you guys are great. I will try and  implement as many recommendations given as possible, i appreciate all your help.