# uglified code will not write into file

Tags: javascript, node.js, uglifyjs

i want to traverse the directory and get the .js files and uglifying using uglifyjs and node.js but i have some problems with my code. below is my code :

```
var mkdirp = require( 'mkdirp' ),
    walk = require( 'walk' ),
    fs = require( 'fs' ),
    jsp = require( 'uglify-js' ).parser,
    pro = require( 'uglify-js' ).uglify,
    files   = [],
    htmlfilestouglify = [];
// Walker options
var walker  = walk.walk( 'shreedhar/www' , { followLinks: false } );

walker.on('file', function( root, stat, next ) {
    // Add this file to the list of files
    files.push(root + '/' + stat.name);
    next();
});

walker.on( 'end', function() {
    for( var i=0; i<files.length; i++){
        // console.log(files[i]);
        var ext = files[i].split( '.' ).pop();
        if( ext == 'js' ){ 
            console.log( files[i] );
            var orig_code = fs.readFileSync( files[i] ).toString(); //read the content of the file

            // create directory
            var fnarr = files[i].split('/'),
                fname = fnarr.pop( files[i].length-1 ),

                dirlen = fnarr.length,
                dirname = fnarr.slice( 0, dirlen ).join('/');

            mkdirp('build/'+dirname );

            // create file
            fs.open('build/'+dirname+'/'+fname, 'w');

            // uglify the content of the file
            var ast = jsp.parse(orig_code); // parse code and get the initial AST
            ast = pro.ast_mangle(ast); // get a new AST with mangled names
            ast = pro.ast_squeeze(ast); // get an AST with compression optimizations
            var final_code = pro.gen_code(ast); 


            // write uglified code into file

            fs.writeFileSync('build/'+dirname+'/'+fname, final_code); 

        }
        else if( ext == 'html'){
            htmlfilestouglify.push(files[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

problem is : if i comment the writeFileSync and run the above code it will create the directory and once again after un commenting the writeFileSync and run, it will write the minified code into files, i couldnt figure out the problem with my code.. can anyone please help me out.

Comment: try using `fs.openSync` instead of `fs.open`...i'm just guessing your problem might be there

Comment: @mihai actually i used asynchronous mkdirp, and by using mkdirp.sync(); solved my problem.

Comment: @mihai sir, is there anything like uglifyjs to uglify the html markup?

Comment: @shreedhar .. once you are done with the code. Please share with us. It will be helpful. Thanks

Comment: @AdilMalik sure, give me your e-mail id, i can share it.

Comment: @shreedhar .. I have also created a java program to do this. But I am using YUI compressor instead of uglifyjs and node.js. You may want to take a look at my blog: http://adilsblogs.blogspot.com/2012/07/obfuscating-multiple-js-files-using-yui.html

Comment: @shreedhar .. I am not sure if we can share personal contacts here? Are you sure it's ok if you post my email id here?

Comment: @AdilMalik  
you can reach me at shreedhar888@gmail.com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `mkdirp` is asynchronous. Call the synchronous version and it should work:

```
mkdirp.sync('build/' + dirname);
```

Comment: sir, is there anything like uglifyjs to uglify the html markup?

Comment: @shreedhar you can't _really_ uglify HTML markup, tags at least can't change (even if you send "uglified" tags you have to restore them with JS and then they'll be available). You may generate ugly IDs and class names but it won't really make your HTML unreadable.

Comment: atleast can we remove whitespaces?

Comment: @shreedhar yes, you can minify HTML (if you **really** need it), check this post here on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification

Comment: sir, im thinking to add this code snippet into my blog. its working fine for my problem statement, is ther any ways to improve this snippet before put into my blog?