# minify html output to one line

Tags: cakephp, minify

Just take a look at [Ask.com](http://www.ask.com) homepage source. It's one long line.

How to remove line-breaks and other unnecessary codes from final html output? (`Views` content)

forexample:

```
<div id="test">
    <span>Hello World!</span>
</div>
```

to:

```
<div id="test"><span>Hello World!</span></div>
```

Can GZip do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Html minification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification)

Comment: no, I ask for CakePHP, not for normal PHP. I want to know where can I put my minification function to minify whole output.

Comment: Unless you're Google and have millions of hits every day I don't know why you would want to do this. We're talking a few bytes saved AFTER gzipping the stream.

Answer (score 3):

I haven't had time to implement this myself yet however this helper looks good.

https://github.com/plyst/cakephp-minifyhtml-plugin

You can also use the following to minify the rest of your assets

https://github.com/markstory/asset_compress/

Answer (score 1):

You may use the helper in this bakery article: http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/tiutalk/2010/07/09/output-valid-and-clean-x-html-with-tidyhelper

To get it all on one line, you may replace

```
return $output;
```

with

```
return preg_replace('/\r?\n/m', '', $output);
```