# How to convert multiline html code to single line html code

Tags: java, javascript, html, css

My code is
test.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h1>My First Heading</h1>

<p>My first paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

converting to

```
<!DOCTYPE html><html><body><h1>My First Heading</h1><p>My first paragraph.</p></body></html>
```

I am using manual converting , please tell me there is any online converter for converting multiline html code to single line html

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: you could search `html minifier` and question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification

Comment: There are numerous HTML "minifiers" around, however I'd think that this post would be off-topic for Stack Overflow - see the [help/dont-ask] on what not to ask for more details.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try this :

Minify HTML (or XHTML), and any CSS or JS included in your markup

http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Answer (score 5):

Have yuou heard about this?

http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/

Or This

http://www.textfixer.com/html/compress-html-compression.php

Answer (score 3):

Check below good site

[minifier](http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a website that claims to do this..
http://www.odditysoftware.com/page-webtools16.htm

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [StringUtils.chomp](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#chomp%28java.lang.String%29)

```
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(FILE_NAME));
        String s = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        while((s = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
        {
            stringBuilder.append(StringUtils.chomp(s));
        }

        System.out.println("stringBuilder : "+stringBuilder);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use any of the following to do this:

http://www.willpeavy.com/minifier/  or
     http://www.iwebtool.com/html_optimizer

Answer (score 0):

use http://htmlcompressor.com/compressor/ 
Click 'Show options' and check 'Single line html output'