# Regex PHP to find and replace white space and,or new line between HTML tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I will have a string (one line) composed by a HTML code that will be stored in a PHP variable. This string comes from a HTML page that normally has new line and white spaces between tags. We can have new line (one or more) and, or white space like this exemle:

```
<h1>tag1</h> 
       <p>Between h ad p we have \s and \n</p>
```

After perform a regex and preg_replace I would like to have this:

```
<h1>tag1</h><p>Between h ad p we have \s and \n</p>
```

I have tried this regex but it is not workig.

```
$str=<<<EOF
<h1>tag1</h> 
           <p>Between h ad p we have \s and \n</p>

EOF;


$string =  trim(preg_replace('/(>\s+<)|(>\n+<)/', ' ', $str));
```

Here you can find the entire code http://www.phpliveregex.com/p/7Pn

Comment: possible duplicate of [HTML minification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification)

Comment: Hi Glavic, it could work, but I need the regex expression behind the scenes. This site do the job http://kangax.github.io/html-minifier/

Comment: See the footer: *Source and bugtracker are hosted on Github.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with

```
(preg_replace('/(>\s+<)|(>\n+<)/', ' ', $str)
```

- `\s` already includes `\n` hence there is no need to provide another alternation.
- `(>\s+<)`here the regex consumes both the angulars `<` and `>` hence replacing with space  would remove everything including the angulars

The output is

```
<h1>tag1</hp>Between h ad p we have \s and \n</p>
```

which is not what you want

**How to correct**

use the regex `(>\s+<)` and replacement string as `><` giving output as

```
<h1>tag1</h><p>Between h ad p we have \s and \n</p>
```

for example http://regex101.com/r/dI1cP2/2

you can also use lookaround to solve the issue

the regex would be

`(?<=>)\s+(?=<)`

and replace string would be empty string

**Explanation**

`(?<=>)` asserts that `\s` is presceded by `>`

`\s+` matches one or more space

`(?=<)` asserts the `\s` is followed by `<`

Here the look arounds *will not* consume any angular brackets as in the earlier regex

see http://regex101.com/r/dI1cP2/3 for example

Comment: Hi nu11p01n73R, infact there is a letter "g" (modifiers) outside the regex that makes the difference. So should we use like this inside a php code `preg_replace("/(>\s+<)/g", "><", $str);` ?

Comment: There is no "g" modifiers in php http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php

Comment: @zwitterion glad to hear it worked :) Hope you resolved the issues

Comment: yes in fact, for preg_replace in php we dont need to use "g" modifier. thnks

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this:

```
echo preg_replace("/(?=\>\s+\n|\n)+(\s+)/", "", $str);
```

Comment: What if they use windows server?

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, Sorry i don't have experience with Windows Server yet, Can you ellaborate hows its not working on windows server?

Comment: A lot of times windows will use "\r\n" for the line ending. So just "\n" may not match.

Answer (score 0):

```
(?<=<\/h>)\s+
```

Try this.See demo.Replace by `empty string`

http://regex101.com/r/jI8lV7/1