# Save Space Using Just Every Other P?

Tags: html

I found that the end result is the same if you code the "normal" way like this:

```
<p>
This is a paragraph text section.
</p>
<p>
This is a paragraph text section.
</p>
<p>
This is a paragraph text section.
</p>
<p>
This is a paragraph text section.
</p>
```

compared to coding like this, in which only every other paragraph text is coded with p:

```
This is a paragraph text section.
<p>
This is a paragraph text section.
</p>
This is a paragraph text section.
<p>
This is a paragraph text section.
</p>
```

This would save space, but are there any compelling reasons to not do it this way?

Comment: For one, any css applicable to `p` wouldn't be applied to the skipped paragraphs. Instead of mutilating the Html, look [at minifying it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728260/html-minification) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed out by @StuartLC:

> css applicable to p wouldn't be applied to the skipped paragraphs

While your code risks this behavior, you could still minify it by taking into account that the closing `p` tag is [optional](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/syntax.html#optional-tags) in HTML5.  Google's Style Guide even recommends [omitting optional tags](https://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/htmlcssguide.xml?showone=Optional_Tags#Optional_Tags).

So you could write the code like this, without losing any `p` CSS properties:

```
<p>This is a paragraph text section.
<p>This is a paragraph text section.
<p>This is a paragraph text section.
<p>This is a paragraph text section.
```

**Snippet**

```css
body {font: 13px verdana;}
p {color: red;}
```

```html
<strong>Alternating `p` elements:</strong>
<p>This is a paragraph text section.</p>
This is a paragraph text section.
<p>This is a paragraph text section.</p>
This is a paragraph text section.
<hr>
<strong>With no closing `p` tags:</strong>
<p>This is a paragraph text section.
<p>This is a paragraph text section.
<p>This is a paragraph text section.
<p>This is a paragraph text section.
```